# Where to create GIT tag on master or branches and merging activity

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I am new to Git, I have 2 question as below, please help me to understand.

1. I have master and testrelease branch, I am planning to merge testrelease branch to master, I want know is it I need to create tag on master and than merge testrelease branch to master? or I need to create tag on testrelease branch an than merge it to master.
2. I have master and 2 other branch, I have new branch(current working branch) which I need to merge back to master and to others 2 branch. my question is, is it need to merge first to master and than from master to other 2 branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Merge first into master and then tag the commit.
2. It depends on the work. If they're each independent branches spawned from the same branch, such as master, then merge back into master and then merge/rebase other feature/fixes into the other branches. If they've been created from each other as sub branches, then merge back into original base first and eventually converge back to master last.

You might also find this Git flow model useful: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/